# How to remove special character from String in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need get value without special character from string

I tried this code but remove special character and letter

**example :**

```
var str = ".34!44fgf)(gg#$qwe3"
    str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)//result => 34443
```

i am want results the following without special character => "3444fgfggqwe3"

Please Advise

Answer (score 1):

You can filter all characters that are letter or digits:

```
let result = str.filter { $0.isLetter || "0"..."9" ~= $0 }

print(result)   // "3444fgfggqwe3"
```

If you would like to restrict the letters to only lowercase letters from "a" to "z"

```
"a"..."z" ~= $0
```

or "A" to "Z"

```
"A"..."Z" ~= $0
```

Comment: Why not `{ $0.isLetter || $0.isNumber }`? 

Comment: @vadian `isLetter` would allow other characters other than the regular alphabet (a to z), `isNumber` would allow fractions. There is also `isWholeNumber` but it is not restricted to `0...9`

Answer (score 0):

Actually `result` is a huge array with a lot of empty strings.

This is another approach with Regular Expression

```
var str = ".34!44fgf)(gg#$qwe3"
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^[0-9a-zA-z]]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Why not a simple filter?

Comment: You provided `filter`, I provided *another approach*.

Comment: split method would avoid the empty strings `split { !($0.isWholeNumber || $0.isLetter) }.joined()`